# docopt not showing usage string after converting python script to .exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, docopt

I'm working on a simple python command line tool which uses docopt.
It works perfectly fine as it is.

However upon being converted to .exe (using pyinstaller), the functions of the script still work but it no longer displays the usage string when no arguments/ incorrect arguments are given.
Also it is significantly slower than original script.

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it !.

I had built the executable by running the following command

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w main.py
```

The -w optional argument is responsible for suppressing the console output

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

This is what should have been run